# 2D animation - how to revert changes?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d, object-mode, layers

Total first-timer here. I’m trying to make an animation using multiple layers within one stroke object. Suddenly all of the lines from each layer are orange, the same thickness and visibility regardless of which keyframe I'm on, and polygonal. Lines in the current keyframe also have an orange border around them. This is visible in draw mode and object mode, I don’t know how I did this or how to get out of it. I can’t deselect the layers without deselecting the whole object in object mode, and when I click on the stroke object again it remains the same. Any new lines I make in any new or existing keyframe have the same properties. The video output does NOT look like this, and the lines look and behave like they are supposed to. I don’t know what mode this is or how to progress, please help!! [image: screenshot of draw mode. all lines look like they are stacked on top of each other regardless of keyframe] [image: screenshot of object mode. lines on the current keyframe are highlighted in an orange border, this is the only difference object mode makes in terms of how the lines look] [image: closeup of object mode]